# Reason behind implicit returns usage in Swift

Tags: swift

Do you know what is the **rationale** behind usage of **implicit returns** in **single-expression closures** in **Swift**?

Is it just a way to make code cleaner and neater or is there any hidden performance gain associated with that?

Thanks, 
Piotr

Comment: cleaner and neater

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's only to look cleaner. There is no hidden performance gain, and even if there was, it would be so small nothing could track it. The only reason for it is to be cleaner and neater, as Swift is that. The rationale is that it will be easier to read.